# Outputing Binary Search Tree Array

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I want to output binary search tree given an array of values. It follows the Binary search tree principle. The diagram is rotated to the left.
This is the desired output:

```
                  <6 
            <5
      4<
3<          
            <2
      1<
```

But it outputs like this
[image]

How do i fix it?

```
//class Node
class Node {
    int value;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    Node(int x) {
        value = x;
    }
}

//class BST
public class BST {
    static int value[] = {3,4,5,6,1,2};
    public static Node root;

    public static Node insert(int num[], int start, int end) {
        if (start > end)
            return null;

        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        Node roots = new Node(value[mid]);
        roots.left = insert(value, start, mid - 1);
        roots.right = insert(value, mid + 1, end);

        display(roots, 0);
        return roots;
    }

    public static void display(Node node, int level){
        if(node!=null){
            display(node.right, level+1);
            System.out.println("");
            if(node==root)
                System.out.print("Root-> ");
            for(int i=0;i<level&&node!=root;i++)
                System.out.print("             ");
            System.out.print(node.value+"< ");
            display(node.left, level+1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        insert(value, 0, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not insert value correctly, your final tree is not a BST (1 has a greater number in left node, but 3 has a greater node at its right).
If you want your insertion to work, your array must be already sorted.
If you want to keep your value array unsorted you need to do rotation during insertion, you should looking to wikipedia or rosetta code for more information

Comment: I edited my code and you're right, i have to sort it! I'll find an algo on how to sort it. Thanks!

Comment: The most interesting part of using an BST is to know how to insert random values, not sorted values. In your case, it was trivial to insert values using a sorted array, but you really should try to insert values in a random way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code with sorted array:

```
public class BST {
    static int value[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    public static Node root;

    public static Node insert(int[] num) {
        if (num.length == 0)
                return null;

        return insert(num, 0, num.length - 1);
    }

    public static Node insert(int num[], int start, int end) {
        if (start > end)
            return null;

        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        Node roots = new Node(value[mid]);
        roots.left = insert(value, start, mid - 1);
        roots.right = insert(value, mid + 1, end);

        return roots;
    }

    public static void display(Node node, int level){
        if(node!=null){
            display(node.right, level+1);
            System.out.println("");
            if(node==root)
                System.out.print("Root-> ");
            for(int i=0;i<level&&node!=root;i++)
                System.out.print("             ");
            System.out.print(node.value+"< ");
            display(node.left, level+1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        display(insert(value), 0);
    }
}
```